# How not to print elements in array that is already in the previous row of the array in java?

Tags: java

For example how can i print all of the elements of this array without printing "2" again using loop

```java
String[][] a={{"1","2"},{"2","3"}};
```

Desired output

```
1 2 3
```

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer (home)work questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: It is always a 2-D array ?

Comment: `Stream.of(a).flatMap(Stream::of).distinct()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the previous printed value in HashSet, check whether the HashSet already exists when printing next time, if it exists do not print, else print

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] a = { { "1", "2" }, { "2", "3" } };

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            String value = a[i][j];

            if (!set.contains(value)) {
                System.out.print(value + " ");
                set.add(a[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[][] matrix = { { "1", "2" }, { "2", "3" } };
Set<String> unique = new LinkedHashSet<>();

for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++)
    unique.addAll(Arrays.asList(matrix[row]));

System.out.println(String.join(" ", unique));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] a={{"1","2"},{"2","3"}};
        int number = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            //System.out.println(a[i]);
            
            for(int p=0; p<a[i].length; p++) {
                if(a[i][p].equals("2")) {
                    number++; 
                }
                if(number == 1) { //Use this to allow how many times you want to print number 2 in this case
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(a[i][p]);
            }
        }

    }
```